# CSS problems with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have this page http:/www.digitalking.it/fxmypics which is ok showing in IE and Firefox, but i have problems using Chrome.

Seems the css is not applied well, here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="box1"><?php if (function_exists('easing_slider')){ easing_slider(); }; ?></div> 
    <div class="box2"><p><a href="<?php echo site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=' . get_permalink()); ?>" title="Register">REGISTER</a> / <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>" title="Login">LOGIN</a></p>
    <div class="arrow"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/arrow.png" width="22" height="35" /></div>
    <div class="upload"><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/upload/">UPLOAD</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and the following the CSS:

```
#slider  .box1 { width: 490px; float:left;  } 

#slider  .box2 { width: 460px; float:left; } 

#slider  .box2 p { text-align: center; font-family: 'Dancing Script', 'Droid Serif', serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 24px; background: url(../images/border1.png) center 0px no-repeat; position: relative; top:-10px; height:40px; padding:14px; } 

#slider  .box2 a:hover { text-decoration: none; } 

#slider .arrow  { text-align: center; position: relative; top:-10px; }

#slider  .upload  { text-align: center; font-family: 'Dancing Script', 'Droid Serif', serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 24px; background: url(../images/border2.png) center 0px no-repeat; position: relative; top:0px; height:25px; padding:14px; }

#slider  .upload a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

What is wrong?

Thanks
Simone

Comment: Do you have any other css styling these?

Comment: The page you mention in your post does not appear to be responding. We'd have to see the page in action to see what is wrong.